# Rounding Off decimal to two places

Tags: c#, parsing, math, type-conversion

I have a decimal variable which contains values like `0.9`,`1.8` etc.Now ,i have to convert these values to like this `0.90`, `1.80.` .Here is the code that i have tried to rounding off to two decimal places but it is giving me the same previous values only..

```
decimal Cost = noof * Rate;

Cost = Math.Round(Cost , 2);
```

Please help me ..

Comment: Given 0.9 === 0.90, How are you printing them

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

0.9 and 0.90 are the same value, you just want to display it differently.

You can use the following:

```
Cost.ToString("0.00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the two numbers are exactly the same(data type and content), the only different between them are the way of displaying or the way of formatting numerical result.

You can format numeric results by using the *String.Format* method, or through the *Console.Write* or *Console.WriteLine* method, which calls *String.Format*. The format is specified by using format strings.

The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx) contains the supported standard format strings with description and examples.

[image]

And you can find more information related to formatting types there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

```
double value = 0.9;
string formattedValue = value.ToString("N2");
```